# Crystal Reports: Add Values from different data records

Tags: crystal-reports, addition, crosstab

I have 2 columns, one column that returns a code (a1, a2, a3, etc) and another column that returns a dollar value for each code.

Name Code Dollar
John a1 1
John a2 2
John a3 2
John b1 4

I want the codes to be their own columns and add similar codes to return one dollar value
Name A B
John 5 4
I'm not sure how to create the formula for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create formulas, for example formula A
a1+a2+a3
and use the formula instead of the fields